# Proving that $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ if and only if $ad = bc$

Tags: real-analysis, fractions

I was working on a problem which asked:

> Prove that $ \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} $ if and only if $ad=bc$, provided $c,d \neq 0$.

Is it sufficient to manipulate $ \frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} $ via multiplications to reach $ad=bc$? Or is there something more? My feeling is, yes, it is enough, because making valid algebraic manipulations to both sides of an equation should, I think, yield an equivalent statement.
Insight would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does d! mean?

Comment: @user276387 I presume he means $c,d  \neq 0$, which makes sense.

Comment: Also algebraic manipulation should be sufficient to prove this. Are you working with the field axioms here?

Comment: The general idea is right, but you have to write it up correctly. Either treat the two directions separately (my preference)  or make the logic clear by using if and only if appropriately, I would consider $(bd)\frac{a}{b}=(bd)\frac{c}{d}$ inadequate.

Comment: You've tagged this question as a real-analysis one; are you trying to prove this from the construction of the real numbers? It's difficult for us to assess what's sufficient without you telling us the context in which you encountered this problem. Also, please make your titles more specific to the question in the future. Titles such as "If and only if (Real Analysis)" and "Differential Equations (Prove)" are extremely unhelpful.

Comment: It depends on the class and the text.  Showing that a/b = c/d => ad = bc by multiplication is trivially easy (although 9 times out of 10 we completely forget to show the converse, ad = bc => a/b = c/d [and then we  forget to state that b and d != 0]).  The *point* is to do it *using the abstract rules of axioms* as presented.  The axioms are doing the exact same thing but... how do we know b(a/b) = a?  That bd(a/b) = bd? how do we know that if a/b = c/d that it follows that bd(a/b) = bd(c/d)?  And so on.  The idea is just to show that you know how to *refer* to axioms as verification.

Answer (score 4):

$$ab^{-1}=cd^{-1} \iff (ab^{-1})(bd)=(cd^{-1})(bd) \iff a(b^{-1}b)d=(cd^{-1})(db)$$
$$ \iff ad=c(d^{-1}d)b \iff ad=cb \iff ad=bc.$$

---

Notes:

- I think you meant "provided $b,d \neq 0$".
- The right side took some time to catch up.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you're doing. If you are at the stage where rational numbers are being introduced and constructed from the integers, the fact that
$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
ad=bc
$$
is part of the *definition* of the rational number $\dfrac{a}{b}$. So there's nothing to prove.

If you are at a different stage, when the quotient $a/b$ has already been introduced and the basic fact that
$$
\frac{a}{b}=ab^{-1}
$$
is known, then you can just manipulate.

Suppose $a/b=c/d$; then we can multiply both sides by $bd$ and the equality is preserved:
$$
\frac{a}{b}bd=\frac{c}{d}bd
$$
that can be rewritten, using commutativity of multiplication, as
$$
ab^{-1}bd=cd^{-1}db
$$
that becomes
$$
ad=cb
$$
Commutativity yields $ad=bc$.

Suppose instead $ad=bc$; then multiply both sides by $b^{-1}d^{-1}$, which you can do because $b\ne0$ and $d\ne0$. So
$$
adb^{-1}d^{-1}=bcb^{-1}d^{-1}
$$
and rearranging terms with commutativity, easily yields
$$
ab^{-1}=cd^{-1}
$$
or
$$
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a,b),(c,d)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^*$.

Multiplying by $b$, one has: $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\Rightarrow a=\frac{bc}{d}\tag{1}.$$

Since $b\neq 0$, multiplying by $\displaystyle\frac{1}{b}$, one has: $$a=\frac{bc}{d}\Rightarrow\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}.\tag{2}$$

Therefore, according to $(1)$ and $(2)$, one has: $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\Leftrightarrow a=\frac{bc}{d}\tag{3}.$$

Proceeding the same way with $d\neq 0$, one has: $$a=\frac{bc}{d}\Leftrightarrow ad=bc.\tag{4}$$

Finally, it follows from $(3)$ and $(4)$ that: $$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}\Leftrightarrow ad=bc.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$

Multiply by $a^{-1}$ on both sides.(We are using the multiplicative inverse of a, following the axioms of real numbers)
I am only writing the basics.

$\frac{1}{b}=\frac{c}{ad}$ (We use the multiplicative identity on the LHS to obtain the $1$. This is repeated in the other steps also.)

Using multiplicative inverse of $\frac{1}{d}$ on both sides.

$\frac{d}{b}=\frac{c}{a}$

using multiplicative inverse of $\frac{1}{b}$ on both sides.

$d=\frac{cb}{a}$

using multiplicative inverse of $\frac{1}{b}$ on both sides.

$ad=bc$, hence shown.

Answer (score 1):

The detailed proof is a bit lengthy to develop here and involves fundamental results on algebraic structures. Given some set $E$ and a law of composition on it $(x,y)\mapsto x.y$, one can define **the set of fractions with numerators in $E$ and denominators in some *non empty* subset $S$ of $E$**. This set can be conveniently defined if the law on $E$ commutative, associative, has an identity element $1$; in other words when **$E$ is a commutative monoïd**.

Fractions are defined as elements of the quotient set $(E\times \overline {S})/R$ i.e. as classes of equivalence modulo R where  $\overline S$ is the stable subset (for the considered law) of $E$ generated by $S$ and $R$ is an equivalence on the set $E\times \overline{S}$ defined by $R(x,y):\exists a\in E,\exists c\in E, \exists b\in \overline{S},\exists d\in \overline{S},\exists s\in \overline{S}$ such that $x=(a,b), y=(c,d) \wedge a.d.s= b.c.s$

In $(E\times \overline {S})/R$ the class of equivalence represented by pair $(a,b)$ i.e. $[(a,b)]_R$ is noted $a/b$. It is the fraction of 
numerator $a\in E$ and denominator $b\in \overline S$. One can induce on this quotient set, a law defining it by $(a/b).(a'/b') = (a.a' / b.b')$ which is commutative, associative, has an identity element the fraction $1/1$: one can briefly and refer to $(E\times \overline {S})/R$ as to  **the (commutative) monoid of fractions with numerators in $E$ and denominators in $S$**. It results from equivalence $R$ that for any two fractions:

$a/b=c/d \iff (\exists s\in \overline{S}) s.a.d=s.b.c$ (0)

and also that every fraction $a/b$ is  equal to $s.a/s.b$ for any $s,b\in \overline S$ and $a\in E$. In particular $s/s=1/1$ $\forall s\in \overline{S}$. Since $(s/1).(1/s)=s/s$, every $s/1$ is invertible $\forall s\in \overline{S}$ having fraction $1/s$ as an inverse. One can *write*  $(s/1)^{-1}=1/s$.

One can further consider the mapping from $E$ into  $(E\times \overline {S})/R$ defined by $h(a)=a/1$. It is a unital morphism of monoids since $h(a.b)=(a.b)/1= (a/1).(b/1)=h(a).h(b)$ and $h(1)=1/1$. Every fraction $a/b$ ($a\in E,b\in \overline S$) can be written in terms of $h$ under the form $h(a).{h(b)}^{-1}$. From (0) one gets:

$h(a)=h(c) \iff (\exists s\in \overline{S}) s.a.=s.c$ (1)

Let $C_E$ be the set of all **cancellable** elements of $E$. ($C_E\neq \emptyset$ since $1\in C_E$).
One can show it is sub-monoid  of E in particular a stable subset $\overline{C_E}=C_E$ of $E$. (if $a$ and $b$ are cancellable so is compound $a.b$)

Reminder: 
$a$ is called left-cancellable (right-cancellable) if $a.x=a.y\rightarrow x=y$ ($x.a=y.a\rightarrow x=y$) $\forall x,y\in E$. It is called 
cancellable when both right-and-left cancellable. If the law to be considered is commutative a right-cancellable element is also left-cancellable and vice-versa, hence cancellable.

From (1): Morphism $h$ is injective iff $\overline S\subset C_E$

$\overline{S}\subset C_E\rightarrow S\subset  C_E$. Conversely $S\subset  C_E \rightarrow \overline S\subset \overline{C_E}=C_E$. In other words $S\subset C_E\iff \overline S\subset C_E$. Hence:

*Morphism $h$ is injective iff  $S\subset C_E$*

Let us suppose $h$ injective now (i.e. $S\subset C_E$) 
$a/b=c/d \iff (\exists s\in S) (s.a.d=s.b.c)$. But now $s.a.d = s.b.c\iff a.d.=b.c.$ (due to the cancellability of every $s\in S$). 
Then one gets,

$a/b=c/d \iff  a.d=b.c$

---

#### Conclusion

**Let $E$ be a commutative monoid. 
$a/b=c/d \iff  a.d=b.c$  holds between any two elements of *the* 
commutative monoid of fractions of numerators in $E$ and denominators 
in some $S(\subset E)$ if and only if, all the denominators are cancellable elements for the law of composition on $E$ (i.e. $S\subset C_E$).**

You can apply this result to the case $E=\mathbb R$ and $S=\mathbb R^*$.

Hope this helps